# reference error can't find xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, api

Trying to get my code to connect to API and retrieve a list of local farmers markets but keep getting Reference error that `xmlhttp` is not defined on line 40. Haven't caught any spelling errors and have tried moving chunks of code to see if they work at different positions.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Markets</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {

                function myFunction(arr) {
                    out = "<h1>Markets</h1>";
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < array.results.length; i++) {
                        out = out + "<em>" + item.marketname + "</em><br>" + details.marketdetails.Address + "</p>"
                        arr.results.forEach(printDetails)

                    }
                    document.getElementById("market_details").innerHTML = out;
                }

                var mybutton = document.getElementById("submit_btn")
                mybutton.onclick = function() {

                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value
                    var url = "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=" + zip;

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                            myFunction(myArr);
                        }
                    }
                };

                xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

            itemsProcessed = 0

            function printDetails(item, index, array) {

                console.log(item.marketname)

                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url2 = "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/mktDetail?id=" + id;

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        var myDArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        details = myDArr

                        //console.log(myDArr.marketdetails)

                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", url2, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();

                    itemsProcessed++
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Find Your Local Market!<h1>
     Enter Zip Code:<input id="zip"></p><br>
    <button id = "submit_btn">Submit</button>
    <div id="market_details"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please specify in which line you know/think the problem is. If you say "line 40" probably no one will take the time to count to line 40 :)

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you define the `xmlhttp` inside the `onclick` handler and you use it outside the handler:

```
mybutton.onclick = function() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //<-- This must be used from inside the current function
    //Your code here
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true); //<-- put this inside the function
    xmlhttp.send(); //<-- put this inside the function
}
```

The second problem is that you `open` and `send` the `XMLHttpRequest` inside the `onreadystatechange` handler:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myDArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        details = myDArr

        //console.log(myDArr.marketdetails)

    };

    itemsProcessed++
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url2, true);//<-- put this outside the onreadystatechange  handler
xmlhttp.send();//<-- put this outside the onreadystatechange  handler
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. I moved what you suggested and I don't get the error message anymore.